# JavaScript is not working on cPanel in CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-3

In my project I am using AJAX for depending dropdown value. It is working well in `localhost` but when I am running this project in cPanel, the AJAX url is not working and no value is coming from response.

jQuery is working well. Why is the communication not happening?

```
$("#area_name_project").on("change", function(e)
  { 
    $('#subarea_name_project').html('<option value="#">Select Subarea</option>');

    var areaVal =  $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl+ "projectController/show_subarea_list",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {val:areaVal},
        success: function(data)
        {    
            $.each(data, function(index, row) 
            {               
                $('#subarea_name_project').append('<option value="' + row.subarea_id + '">' + row.subarea_name + '</option>');              
            });
        }
    });
});
```

CodeIgniter `base_url` that I used for AJAX:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/crm/';
```

When I view page source and click on the link it shows  that the `val` that I send from AJAX to controller is undefined.

- What is happening to me here ?
- Should I give the url?

Comment: have you checked on Firefox dev Network tab whether it is sending request or not?

Comment: ok now i have done this with post method and now its getting result but i cant access those . why ?

Comment: First convert JSON string to javascript object first using JSON.parse(data)

Comment: i did many thing and as suggest too but nothing is working ! wokuld you like to see my project and try to catch the prblm for me ? @ striker_axel

Comment: ok give me link of your project

Comment: http://demo.tech2z.com/crm/projectController @ striker_axe

Comment: why showing this error ?  some dot's before value and doctype and on hover saying uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0  =>  ....[{"subarea_id":"1","subarea_name":"Uttara"},{"subarea_id":"2","subarea_name":"Banani"},{"subarea_id":"5","subarea_name":"test"}, {"subarea_id":"6","subarea_name":"ujhhjhj"}]     <=

Comment: first put event.preventdefault() in click callback function. Prevent it from calling submit method.

Comment: done but still cant access return value